# Run again current query via ajax but changing a var

Tags: ajax, query

I have custom query which is `$query`. The input is based on form input. The query has already run on a page, but after that I'd like to run it again without a page reload, so with AJAX (when the users selects a tab (Bootstrap)).

The thing is that I need to change the query var `posts_per_page` to `-1`.

The code to do something when the tab is selected is:

```
$('#myTab').on('shown', function () {
   // Do stuff here
})
```

Now within that function I can do

```
jQuery.ajax(
    {  
        type: 'POST',  
        url: ajaxurl, // example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php is defined in my js file
        data: 
        {  
            action: 'the_function_here',
            ajaxnonce: YTajax.ajaxnonce, // Also defined
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)
        {  
            jQuery('#bodyForOutput').html(data);  
        },  
        error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {  
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

But I don't really know how to make use of `$query` which is already defined. I only need to alter the `posts_per_page`. Can I do this with `set_query_var`? Or is that only usable for the main loop?

Comment: Just to be clear - you're trying to do an ajax request, which returns essentially the same results as the original request except that you want to change `posts_per_page` to `-1` - is that correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to note that an ajax request is an entirely new http request, so the `$query` variable is defined in the page that *send* the ajax request but will be **not** set in the page that *receive* the request.

That means that you have completely recreate the query and not change a param.

That said, you have **2** possibilities:

#### 1: Query is a custom one

If the query is a custom one (you create it using `WP_Query`) you can write a function that return that query and call it from the page and from the function hooking in the ajax action:

```
// in functions.php or in plugin
function my_custom_query( $posts_per_page = 10 ) {
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    // other args here
  ); 
  return new WP_Query( $args );
}

// then inside the page
$query = my_custom_query();
while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
  // your loop code here
}

// and handling ajax action
add_action('wp_ajax_the_function_here', 'my_ajax_loop');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_the_function_here', 'my_ajax_loop');
function my_ajax_loop() {
   $query = my_custom_query( -1 );
   while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
     // your loop code here
   }
   die();
}
```

#### 2: Query is the *main* query

If you want to replicate the main query changing one or more param, cosider to pass the query vars to the script via `wp_localize_script` and the pass them via ajax to the function that handle the ajax action, something like:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'add_my_scripts');

function add_my_scripts() {
  // here I'm assuming the javascript file where you have the code you posted
  // is called 'myscript.js' and resides in 'js' subfolder inside theme folder
  wp_enqueue_script('my_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js');
  global $wp_query;
  $qv = $wp_query->query;
  wp_localize_script('my_script', 'my_script_data', array('query' => $qv) );
}
```

After that, in the js file you can:

```
jQuery.ajax({  
  type: 'POST',  
  url: ajaxurl, // example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php is defined in my js file
  data:  {  
    action: 'the_function_here',
    ajaxnonce: YTajax.ajaxnonce, // Also defined
    query: my_script_data.query // Defined by 'wp_localize_script'
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {  
    jQuery('#bodyForOutput').html(data);  
  },  
  error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Now you can hande the ajax request in like so:

```
// and handling ajax action
add_action('wp_ajax_the_function_here', 'my_ajax_loop');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_the_function_here', 'my_ajax_loop');
function my_ajax_loop() {
   $args = (array) filter_var(INPUT_POST, 'query');
   $args['posts_per_page'] = -1;
   $query = new WP_Query($args);
   while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
     // your loop code here
   }
   die();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My query is a custom one so that's option 1. The custom_query function (which is already there) takes several input variables based on the form input. So I'll grab those from the form, and send them along with the `posts_per_page`.