# Search - Ajax - Alter Query Parameters with Pagination

Tags: wp-query, pagination, ajax, search, paginate-links

**Too Long ; Didn't Read**

How do I get pagination to work when I'm creating my query with ajax?

---

I'm working on creating a functional search page that allows the user to filter how many posts per page. I don't quite understand how to create it so pagination functions correctly and was hoping somebody could explain it to me. I understand that by creating a new query in my PHP ajax action I thus create new paging and do not alter the normal WP_Query, so I would need to make my pagination function with ajax but i'm not sure how I would connect it to a certain ajax custom query.

```
function implement_ajax() {

    $ppp = 10;
    if(isset($_GET['ppp']))
        $ppp = $_GET['ppp'];

    $search = $_GET['s'];           // Acquired and sent via ajax
    $paged = 1;
    if(isset($_GET['paged']))
        $paged = $_GET['paged'];

    $temp = new WP_Query(array('s' => $search, 'posts_per_page' => $ppp));

    $numPosts = $temp->post_count;
    $foundPosts = $temp->found_posts;
    $lastPage = $temp->max_num_pages;

    ob_start();
    if($temp->have_posts()) :
        $i = 0; 
    ?>
        <?php if($temp->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
            <div class="pagination">
                <?php 
                    $big = 999999999;
                    echo paginate_links(array('base' => '/', 'format' => '?paged=%#%', 'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ), 'total' => $temp->max_num_pages)); 
                ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div> <!-- class="pagination" -->
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div id="postContainer">
            <?php while($temp->have_posts()) : 
                    $temp->the_post(); 
                    $i++; 
            ?>

                <div class="custom-post<?php echo ($i%2 == 0) ? ' even' : ''; echo ($i == $numPosts) ? ' last' : ''; echo ($i == 1) ? ' first' : ''; ?>">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div> <!-- class="custom-post" -->

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div> <!-- id="postContainer" -->

    <?php else : ?>
        <div id="postContainer">
            <div id="content">
                <p>No articles found.</p>
                <p><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Return Home</a></p>  
            </div> <!-- id="content" -->
        </div> <!-- id="postContainer" -->
    <?php endif;

    $htmlContent = ob_get_clean();
    echo $htmlContent;
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_implement_ajax', 'implement_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_implement_ajax', 'implement_ajax');
```

The above returns the correct query - but pagination is broken since I'm not sure how to set the `base` parameter. I've tried `('/?s='.$search.'?paged='.$paged)` and `/` and a few other ones that have gotten me nowhere. If I use the 'Basic Example' in The Codex: `str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) )` paginate_links return:

`/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=implement_ajax&ppp=1&s=web&paged=2`

which does return the correct posts, minus the header, footer, and styles.

I tried to duplicate what G.M did in [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124432/run-again-current-query-via-ajax-but-changing-a-var) with localize script but couldn't get past `$args = (array) filter_var(INPUT_POST, 'query');` since parameter 2 was expecting an integer. I tried to just convert my $_POST['query'] to an array but wasn't able to do so.

**Relevant File Pastebins:**

1. [Search Page](http://pastebin.com/SUzdqrgn)
2. [Relevant Functions](http://pastebin.com/AxtZ0zs9)
3. [Ajax Jquery](http://pastebin.com/jZV0ruBS)

Warning - there may be some relics in there, I've been commentings things in and out to try and get this to work.

Comment: What is the actual base of your search page, meaning the literal path: `http://domain.com/your/search/page/%_%`?

Comment: `www.mydomain.com/?s=web` - but if there's paging it goes into `www.mydomain.com/page/2/?s=web` - most my results though (via ajax) are putting paging into the query var (`?paged=2`) instead of rewriting it.

Comment: you get that format because that's what you set the format to in your paginate_links args

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want. `base` is set via `home_url()`, format is `page/%#%/`, search query arg is added via `add_args` if it exists:

```
$args = array(
    'base' => home_url( '/%_%' ),
    'format' => 'page/%#%/',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $temp->max_num_pages,
);

if( isset($_GET['s']) ){
    $args['add_args'] = array(
        's' => $_GET['s'] // your search query passed via your ajax function
    );
}

echo paginate_links( $args );
```

Comment: I think one of the main problems is that I'm generating paginate links from my ajax call - which when I try to locate page 2 it doesn't know how / where to find it. Like I can't even use `get_query_var` in my ajax php function call.

Comment: it knows where to find it in this example because you set it to an absolute value via `home_url()`. you're right about `get_query_var` and the search value, my bad, you have to pass that via javascript.

Comment: the thing to remember about `paginate_links` is that it's not a typical template tag that operates from global vars and whatnot- it's a general purpose pagination function designed to generate links for any type of pagination, and as such it relies completely on you explicitly setting every aspect of what you want as output.

Comment: Ok, so I was able to pull the page via Jquery - now though whenever I click to go to the second page, it brings up the 2nd page of the original WP_Query. So if I click my selectbox 5 posts per page - it runs my ajax, shows 5 posts and the correct pagination, then when I go to page 2 the pagination reverts and it goes back to the original WP_Query of 10 ppp. Thanks for your help btw! - I think I need to connect my paginate_links with my new WP_Query or modify the main WP_Query via ajax (which seems impossible without a full page reload).

Comment: I'd have to see your full code to understand what's happening, but note that if you change posts per page value on a page other than the first, the starting post will be relative to that value times the page number, unless you track the *previous* posts per page times page number, and set an offset.

Comment: I've updated my question with some pastebins. That's an idea of what i'm working with for the search - the select box is in my sidebar and is just a normal selectbox. Can include that if needed but I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: you don't maintain state from one page to the next. when you click a pagination link you run the normal query using the default posts per page. you need to figure out some way to pass what the new posts per page value is in those pagination links and use that value on the next page reload.

Comment: Ok (thinking out loud), I'm using a function to create a new query so the ajax works, this comes with pagination. The problem is when I click one of the paginated links it hits a `$_POST` and not my ajax function. To keep track of what page my ajax function is on I would have to use a global variable and change my static search.php pagination. I was thinking an easier option would be to just make all `paginate_links()` function via ajax. Then I could pass paged variables back and forth via jquery right? The whole thing is more complex than I was expecting and I feel i'm going about it wrong...

Comment: you can append a custom posts per page var to paginate_links the same way you add the s query var, then hook pre_get_posts and look for that var, and set posts_per_page there.

Comment: holy ******* **** it tooks me awhile to realize what exactly the `add-args` parameter was doing but now I understand and it's awesome (Passes args as `$_GET`). So it ended up totally working. Thank you for the help / pointing me in the right direction. [Here's what I've updated](http://pastebin.com/F6M1HGEq) as far as my code goes - if you could update your answer with a little more detail and code that may be helpful to future readers than the comments. Thanks again!